# TypeError: Object(..) is not a function React-Router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new to React, so when I try to use React-Router `<BrowserRouter>` I get this error
whenever I delete it, the app works just fine
I'm using React-router v6
here is the error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e44Gr.png)

My index.js
[index.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MAoU.png)

i'm using

> "react": "^16.6.3",
> "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
> "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1"

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many searching, I figured out that the problem was with my React version 16.6
as react router v6 depends heavily on React Hooks which was introduced starting from React v16.8, so I had to either upgrade my react version or downgrade my React router to v5, which I did and worked just fine.
[react router docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdpAP.png)

source:
react router docs
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5

Answer (score 1):

use try it:

```
ReactDom.render(
<>
 <App/>
</>
,document.getElementById("root"))
```

Comment: Yes it works when i remove <BrowserRouter>, but I need to use React Router, and it gets me the error, that's the problem

Comment: I suggested another way

Comment: I tried the second way too, I have been trying for almost 2 days and it was all about the version, thanks again sir

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";

ReactDom.render(
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
       <Route path="/" element={<App />}></Route>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
,document.getElementById("root"))
```

Comment: I really appreciate your great help sir, after all, the problem was in my version of React-Router 6 which needs atleast react v16.8 to use hooks, thanks alot again